# Visual Studio Code doesn't run code

Tags: visual-studio-code, c

Why VS Code doesn't want to run code when I use `scanf()` function to get user's input knowing that without this function the code runs perfectly.

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: Look at the `terminal` tab

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope here at Super User

Comment: It's not really a programming question. It's a "how to use the IDE" question

Answer (score 4):

1. CTRL+SHIFT+X
2. Type in search box ***Code Runner***
3. Install the extension
4. Than click on **File - Preferences - Settings**
5. Type ***code run*** in search box.
6. Scroll down until you find **Code-runner: Run In Terminal**. Check the box **Wheather to run code in Integrated Terminal.**
7. Restart VS Code

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! I installed the C extension and apparently it doesn't enough. So thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

first of all I'm a begginer in VS code so I will try my best to explain how I sort of fixed this "error". Hope this post still helps a lot of people.

What I think is happening is that this C program gets only compiled when you hit "Run Code". I'm not sure about this at all. 
The solution I found is that the right way to actually run your program is by "Start Debugging" (F5).
Now when you go to the .json file where the configuartion for debugging is located.
You simply need to change the line "externalConsole" and set it to "true". And that's basically it. After that you simply Run your program with (F5). Keep in mind that if you change something in your original code you need to run it with "Run Code", 
(ctrl+alt+n) so that the uptades you do get saved and "compiled".

Hope I helped

Line to change:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to run the code in the terminal for that.

In case you want to **debug** none of these solutions worked for me using MacOS Sonomia.

I only got it to work using [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) extension.

For more details refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795969/18578004) on stack-overflow or [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9025#issuecomment-1777156301) on github which shows the solution for debugging

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).